# How to use 自動詞 to describe 名詞?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

According to my teacher, if you want to use 自動詞 to describe 名詞, you should transform 自動詞 to た形, for example

> 彼は優れた人。

But if I want to use the 辞書形 — e.g. 彼は優れる人です — is it meaningful? And can I do like that?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, by changing a verb to describe a noun, (or verb to adjective) it would make more sense to use た形 to describe past tense. 
Since you are making a statement to describe something, it would make more sense to use past tense since the description is 'decided' or in the past? If you follow what I mean.. 
e.g. 彼は優れた人 means he is excellent, but taken literally you can say it means he *has* excelled.(since he *has* excelled in the past, hence he is excellent).